# Why does Bash with -e option exit when 'let' expression evaluates to 0?

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

I am struggling to understand why the bash `-e` option exits this script.
It happens only when the expression calculated gives `0`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
table_year=( 1979 1982 1980 1993 1995 )
year=$1 
let indice=year-1
real_year=${table_year[$indice]}
echo OK $real_year
```

Is is ok when:

```
./bash_test_array 2
```

but not when:

```
./bash_test_array 1
```

`indice` is this case equals to `0`. Why the `-e` option causes an exit ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: @Joe: While the cause may be the same, the problem in this question is expressed much simpler than in that other question (assignment vs. increment side effect).

Answer (score 5):

See `help let`:

> Exit Status:
>   If the last ARG evaluates to 0, let returns 1; let returns 0 otherwise..

The behavior of the `let` builtin is the same as for the commonly used `expr` command:

> Exit status is [...] 1 if EXPRESSION is null or 0 [...]

You can use arithmetic expansion instead:

```
indice=$(( year - 1 ))
```

This statement will return 0 even if the assigned expression evaluates to 0.

Comment: Defintely better than using `let`

Comment: I would add that  

`indice=\`expr $year - 1\``

has the same behaviour as let.

Comment: @PBrockmann: Thanks, `expr` behavior mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following trick:

```
let indice=year-1 || true
```